# Including some dependencies in my compiled jar

Tags: java, slf4j, hikaricp

Hello people of stackoverflow, on my working project I have 5 dependencies. 
I'm working on a project which doesn't contain any main method.

What I would like to do is including 2 (HikariCP and slf4j) out of my 5 dependencies in the final jar, but I don't figure how to do this, it's always adding all of them.

Edit: I'm using eclipse

Comment: Are you using maven?

Comment: No I'm not, but if it's the only option I can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using Maven

You can use the `maven-shade-plugin` to generate a **fat-jar** (or uber-jar). It will package all your dependencies inside the jar:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>YOUR_JAR_FINAL_NAME</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Documentation related to the `maven-shade-plugin` [can be found in here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/usage.html)

**UPDATE:** As you want to include just a few dependencies inside of it, you can check the [Selecting contents for Uber JAR](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) section:

You can use the *include* or *exclude* tag to select which content will be provided to the jar, you can find some examples from the docs below:

- Excluding

  ```
      <configuration>
        <artifactSet>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>classworlds:classworlds</exclude>
            <exclude>junit:junit</exclude>
            <exclude>jmock:*</exclude>
            <exclude>*:xml-apis</exclude>
            <exclude>org.apache.maven:lib:tests</exclude>
            <exclude>log4j:log4j:jar:</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </artifactSet>
      </configuration>
  ```
- Including and excluding

  ```
      <configuration>
        <filters>
          <filter>
            <artifact>junit:junit</artifact>
            <includes>
              <include>junit/framework/**</include>
              <include>org/junit/**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>org/junit/experimental/**</exclude>
              <exclude>org/junit/runners/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </filter>
          <filter>
            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
              <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
              <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </filter>
        </filters>
      </configuration>
  ```

**UPDATE 2:** For a runnable jar file, you can follow [this section of the documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html) related to *Executable Jars*

### In Eclipse

You can use the *Package required libraries into generated JAR* option, the downside of it is that you can't really select which dependencies do you want to include into to, since it is assessing all the required libs for you project.

[image]

I believe if you really want to remove some stuff, you would need to use Maven to package, or remove manually the dependencies you don't like from the generated jar, generating a *custom jar with your own hands*:

[image]

Comment: Will it include just the jars I want and not all of them ?

Comment: You can use `filters` combined with `include` and `exclude` tags, edited my answer with more details.

Comment: By the way I saw that you are not using Maven, so which tool are you using?

Comment: I'm not not using any tool. Only eclise and the export option. Should I use some ?

Comment: Let me edit my answer with the eclipse version. Give me a few minutes

Comment: Another question, are you exporting a runnable jar file?

Comment: I was, but it kept including all the dependencies in it

Comment: Yea unfortunately I don't think it is an option in Eclipse, I complemented my answer please check

Comment: You wrote "remove manually the dependencies you don't like from the generated jar, generating a custom jar with your own hands"

How would I do that, can you redirect to a tutorial or telling me ? 

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yea you can just unzip your jar, remove the dependencies and zip it again. For sure I would not recommend do it, since you are handling runtime dependencies by hand there is a chance of remove something that you should not, causing issues on your app at runtime in some features.